# Devise rails session ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

It turns out that getting the session ID (with `session[:session_id]`) after login with Devise (authentication gem) (either in `session_controller` or in `after_sign_in_path_for`) does not return the same thing before and after redirecting for the first time, after logging-in.

Is anyone able to explain me why ? 
Is there any way to get the final session ID *before* redirecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI answer from Gee-Bee (https://github.com/Gee-Bee):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3706

> ```
> Is anyone can explain me why ?
> ```
>
> I'll try. In short:
>
> ```
> Devise has nothing to do with it
> Warden has something to do with it - it's setting :renew option on session, after setting user (proxy, spec)
> Actual action takes place in in Rake::Session::Abstract#commit_session which updates session_id (by
> ```
>
> calling destroy_session and set_session implementented in
>   ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore)
>
> ```
> Is there any way to get the final session ID before redirecting ?
> ```
>
> Sure it is. Bear in mind that Warden is changing session_id after
>   authentication to prevent session fixation attacks, so in overriden
>   devise controller you should manually change session_id in addition to
>   disabling :renew session option. This will do:
>
> session.options[:id] =
>   session.instance_variable_get(:@by).generate_sid
>   session.options[:renew] = false

Comment: is there a way to get from Warden the new session id after authentication, programmatically?